# Ignoring files that find cannnot search or open?

Tags: scripting, find, command

I searched for big files using this command on HP Unix:

```
find . -type f -size +100000000c -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

The result came out somthing like this:

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 qa1wrk32   test       169263642 Oct 27 12:28 ./rgs/test/qa1wrk32/DB/Dmp/intrefbl01_20111027_Backup_for_qa1ref32_CNSTRNO.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 qa1wrk32   test       173779937 Oct 24 16:33 ./rgs/test/qa1wrk32/DB/Dmp/qa1ref32_20111024_Backup_before_Refresh.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 qa1wrk32   test       105020030 Oct 31 09:53 ./rgs/test/qa1wrk32/DB/Dmp/qa1app32_20111031_R112_Before_CopyBan_from_INT01_to_ENV32_for_LISA_CNSTRNO.dmp.gz
find: cannot open ./rgs/test/maes32/master/.ssh
find: cannot open ./rgs/test/qa1oln32/.ssh
find: cannot open ./rgs/test/qa1oln32/local_tlg/bin/.adm
find: cannot search ./rgs/test/qa1wrk91/mail
```

I don't want the lines of output where find fails to search or open or anything else. Is there a way to filter them out? Better yet, can I make `find` search for files with some set of permissions?

Comment: well I tried this  but it didnt work `find . -type f -size +100000000c -exec ls -lrt {} \;
 | grep -v cannot`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find` prints the errors to `stderr`. If you just want to ignore them, the simplest thing to do is:

```
find ... 2> /dev/null
```

`find` also has the `-perm` option to filter based on permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `find` to search for files with particular permissions, but it's not quite what you need here. You need to tell `find` not to explore directories that you don't have permission to traverse. It's actually easy to tell `find` not to descend into a directory — it's the `-prune` primary — but there's no easy way to match directories that you don't have permission to traverse. In [GNU `find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), you can write `-readable -executable`, but [standard `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) has no such option (nor does [HP-UX `find`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/find.1.html)).

You can reconstruct your access rights from permissions, but it's painful. And on systems that have ACLs (which HP-UX does), you need to take these into account as well.

```
find . -type d \
       \! \( -user $(id -u) -perm -u+rx -o \
             \( -group $(id -G | sed 's/ / -o -group /g') \) -perm -g+rx -o \
             -perm -a+rx \) -prune -o \
     -type f -size +100000000c -exec …
```

In practice, unless this is a mission-critical script, you probably want to [ignore the errors from `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23939/ignoring-files-that-find-cannnot-search-or-open/23943#23943). (And if it's a mission-critical script, write it in some other language that allows better filtering of error conditions, like Perl or Python.)

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer because i like you mentioning  that what i can't do when it comes to a certain *nix(like HP-unix), and suitable option for doing this. good explanation.Thanks